Как загрузить телеграм бота на GitHub Pages
У меня есть телеграмм бот написанный на python. Мне нужно разместить его на GitHub Pages. Я не могу разобраться как это сделать. Я создал свой репозиторий на github. Теперь мне нужно как то этот репозиторий разместить на GitHub Pages. Буду очень благодарен за подробную инструкцию.

Это невозможно.

Ну ведь это хостинг виртуальная машина , разве она не будет работать с ботом ?

Если разработчики гитхаба не реализовали такую возможность - конечно не будет

github pages - это хостинг статических файлов (например, html+css+js). Произвольный сервис там не запустишь

"Виртуалка" (github actions) может использоваться только для подготовки файлов, но не будет постоянно висеть и ждать запросов, как настоящий веб-сервис.
